# ReactJS:'languagefunction' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: reactjs

I am using react framework to call a function from one component(languagefunction.js) to other component app.js

**languagefunction.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const languagefunction= () => <h1>hello Sir</h1>

export default languagefunction
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {Dropdown,DropdownButton}from 'react-bootstrap';
import Login from "./components/login.component";
import SignUp from "./components/signup.component";
import languagefunction from "./components/languagefunction";

function App() {
  return (<Router>
    <div className="App">
    <languagefunction/>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
        <div className="container">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to={"/sign-in"}>Tira Desk</Link>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to={"/sign-in"}>Sign in</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to={"/sign-up"}>Sign up</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
          <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Dropdown button">
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey="english_language">English</Dropdown.Item>
          <Dropdown.Item eventKey="tamil_language">Tamil</Dropdown.Item>
          
          </DropdownButton>
            </li>
            </ul>
          </div>       
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div className="outer">
        <p>Testing</p>
        <div className="inner">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
            <Route path="/sign-in" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The issue i am facing is "'languagefunction' is declared but its value is never read."

I have declared the value "import languagefunction from "./components/languagefunction" and used it in ***<*languagefunction/*>***

I hope i have done it right, care to explain what is the mistake i am making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React components need to start with a capital letter, try this instead:

Languagefunction.js

```
const Languagefunction= () => <h1>hello Sir</h1>

export default Languagefunction
```

App.js

```
...
import Languagefunction from "./components/Languagefunction";

function App() {
  return (<Router>
    <div className="App">
    <Languagefunction/>
    ...
```